# Cannot observe Raman signal from Styrofoam

Tags: spectroscopy, raman-spectroscopy, fluorescence

I am trying to build a low cost Raman spectrometer. I am using a refurbished B&WTek spectrometer that I purchased from [eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/B-W-TEK-BRC100-Spectrometer-400-750nm-Power-Supply-Fiber-Optic-BRC100-OEM/142437828855?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649). I calibrated the unit myself and found to be very sensitive and accurate. I am using a reflection probe that I purchased from [here](http://www.aseq-instruments.com/fiberSMA1.html). My setup looks like this:[image: styro] I ran a first pass of the setup: Integration time of 10s and averaging of just one sample. I got the spectrum shown below.Is this fluorescence? If it is, what could be done to suppress it? Anything in my setup that I need to revise? [image]

Edit: Raman scattering from styrofoam is quite strong and looks as follows:[image]

Comment: Why styrofoam? Is styrofoam Raman-active? Does it have strong Raman lines? If yes, then find a published Raman spectrum and compare your plot above to it. If not, then find a better material for your calibration tests. Silicon is supposed to be pretty good since it doesn't fluoresce and has a sharp peak at around 521 $cm^{-1}$.

Comment: Not an expert on Raman, but isn't the strong line that you measured simply the 532nm of your laser? The Raman lines should be quite close to that 532 nm line which, according to my understanding, is what makes Raman a bit difficult to perform because you have to somehow suppress or filter out the strong laser line in order to see peaks that are very close to it.

Comment: Yes thats the line from the laser, however for 1000cm-1 shift, the scattered wavelength should be ~562nm, so it should ideally be visible.

Comment: The Raman signal will be orders of magnitude down from the laser. Rescan in the area of interest at high gain and long integration times.

Comment: @Jon the signal floor already seems quite elevated due to fluorescence, wouldn’t the Raman signal be buried deep in it? How could I recover it?

Comment: @user1155386 - Does styrofoam fluoresce? Or is the background elevated simply due to small amounts of the intense laser light scattering to other channels in your spectrometer/sensor system? The professional Raman setups I've seen involved things like big double monochromators specifically intended to beat down the background due to scattered laser light as much as possible because the very weak Raman lines are so close to the laser line. We have a spectrometer in our lab in a fluorescence studies setup, but it's not considered to be good enough for Raman.

Comment: @JonCuster Valid point! It could be just the intense 532nm beam flooding other channels. The dip at 550nm is what confused me. If this were stray light scattering, I would expect all wavelengths to have some elevated signal levels. And no, I am not aware that styrofoam fluoresces with 532nm excitation. I was trying to make sense of what I was sensing.